# Ansible registered variables are empty when running playbooks with tags

Tags: ansible, tags, ansible-facts

I wanted to run a particular copy task on the playbook every 5min. To do that I used tag for that particular task and ran the playbook with --tags. When I use --tags option the registered variables (pre-task) are passed empty.

My Playbook

```
---
- name: DNS Master and Slave Configuration Playbook
  hosts: "{{ host }}"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no 
  connection: ssh

  pre_tasks:
    - include_tasks: pre_tasks/register_vars.yml
      tags: always

  roles:
    - role1
    - role2 (role with the tagged task)
    - role3
```

I use "when" condition on the task. The task won't work without the registered variables.

```
- name: Copy DNS zone files to the server
  copy:
    src: xx/xx-dns-zones/
    dest: /var/named/data/master/
    owner: named
    group: named
    mode: '0644'
  when: colo.stdout == 'xx' and 'server1' in fqdn.stdout
  notify: reload dns
  tags: xx-zone-files
```

This is my pre_tasks where I register st and colo variables.

```
---
#pre_tasks
- name: To register colo of the server as variable
  shell: /usr/bin/hostname | /bin/awk -F'.' '{print $2}'
  register: colo

- name: To register fqdn of the server as vairble
  shell: /usr/bin/hostname
  register: fqdn
```

When I ran the playbook with --tags the registered variables are passed empty.

```
$ ansible-playbook dns-playbook.yml -e host=xx-server1 --tags "xx-zone-files"

PLAY [Test Playbook] ***************************************************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] *********************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 10 September 2020  10:25:21 +0000 (0:00:00.133)       0:00:00.133 **** 
included: /home/ansibleuser/ansible/pre_tasks/register_vars.yml for xx-server1

TASK [dns : Copy DNS zone files to the server] *******************************************************************************************************
Thursday 10 September 2020  10:25:21 +0000 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:00.156 **** 
fatal: [xx-server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'colo.stdout == 'xx' and 'server1' in fqdn.stdout' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (colo.stdout == 'xx' and 'server1' in fqdn.stdout): 'colo' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/sselvaraj/test/click_ansible/roles/dns/tasks/main.yml': line 96, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n# Copy XX DNS zone files\n- name: Copy DNS zone files to the server\n  ^ here\n"}
```

There are no issues when I run the playbook without tags. The variables are successfully registered and the condition passed.

```
TASK [include_tasks] *********************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 10 September 2020  10:53:49 +0000 (0:00:00.134)       0:00:00.134 **** 
included: /home/ansibleuser/ansible/pre_tasks/register_vars.yml for xx-server1

TASK [To register colo of the server as variable] ****************************************************************************************************
Thursday 10 September 2020  10:53:49 +0000 (0:00:00.021)       0:00:00.156 **** 
changed: [xx-server1] => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": true, "cmd": "/usr/bin/hostname | /bin/awk -F'.' '{print $2}'", "delta": "0:00:00.015379", "end": "2020-09-10 03:53:50.374733", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-09-10 03:53:50.359354", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], **"stdout": "xx"**, "stdout_lines": ["xx"]}

TASK [To register fqdn of the server as vairble] *****************************************************************************************************
Thursday 10 September 2020  10:53:50 +0000 (0:00:00.481)       0:00:00.637 **** 
changed: [xx-server1] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/usr/bin/hostname", "delta": "0:00:00.014439", "end": "2020-09-10 03:53:50.553507", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-09-10 03:53:50.539068", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], **"stdout": "xx-server1.xx.test.com"**, "stdout_lines": ["xx-server1.xx.test.com"]}
```

I want the registered variables to be passed when running the playbook with --tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `--tags`, only tasks that have those tags are executed. So what you can do, is the following:

- Add the `always` tag to the tasks, that are to be executed every time. They will run regardless of `--tags` and `--skip-tags`.
- Add another tag, like `config` to those tasks, and supply `--tags "xx-zone-files,config"` with your command.
- Add the tag `xx-zone-files` to those tags.

As it seems those variables should always be registered, I would go with option one:

```yaml
---
#pre_tasks
- name: To register colo of the server as variable
  shell: /usr/bin/hostname | /bin/awk -F'.' '{print $2}'
  register: colo
  tags: always

- name: To register fqdn of the server as vairble
  shell: /usr/bin/hostname
  register: fqdn
  tags: always
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks, @toydarian I thought as I added always tag on the pre_tasks it won't be necessary to add it to each task.   
pre_tasks:
    - include_tasks: pre_tasks/register_vars.yml
      tags: always

Comment: You need to add the tag on every task you want to tag. What you did was only tagging the pre-task. If you include something. e.g. a role, you can use `apply` to tag tasks in this include. Check [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#parameter-apply).